# Search string in between HTML tags and replace

Tags: html, excel, vba

Newbie here.   I have an HTML source code and would like to look for string in between header tags `<h1></h1>, <h2></h2>`till `<h5></h5>` and then convert the text to lower case except acronyms or abbreviations (these are all capitals in 2 or more characters).   And make sure that all country names in between use proper case.

As an example: It will find `<h1>HR Policies and Procedures for Hiring - argentina LTD</h1>`

It will convert it to:`<H1>HR policies and procedures for hiring - Argentina LTD</H1>`

I've tried a user defined function for Excel VBA found online: CapIt(A2). It uses `Search, Split` and `Join`.   I'm not able to put them together to come up with the result.   Would appreciate very much your help.  Thank you.

Code I saw online as initial reference:

```
Function Capit(s As String) 
Dim v As Variant, j As Long 

v = Split(s, " ") ' separates the words 
For j = LBound(v) To UBound(v) 
     If StrComp(v(j), UCase(v(j)), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then v(j) = StrConv(v(j), vbProperCase) 
Next j 

Capit = Join(v, " ") ' joins the words 

End Function

'Added this code below, can we use the results to lowercase the string and exclude the output in this function

Function FindAcronyms(yourWord As String)
Dim I As Integer
Dim ctr As Integer

FindAcronyms = Null
For I = 1 To Len(yourWord)
    If Asc(Mid(yourWord, I, 1)) <= 90 And _
       Asc(Mid(yourWord, I, 1)) >= 65 Then
       If ctr > 0 Then
          FindAcronyms = FindAcronyms & Mid(yourWord, I - 1, 1)
       End If
       ctr = ctr + 1
    Else
       If ctr > 1 Then
          FindAcronyms = FindAcronyms & Mid(yourWord, I - 1, 1) & ", "
       End If
       ctr = 0
    End If
Next

If ctr > 1 Then
   FindAcronyms = FindAcronyms & Mid(yourWord, I - 1, 1)
End If

If Right(FindAcronyms, 2) = ", " Then
   FindAcronyms = Left(FindAcronyms, Len(FindAcronyms) - 2)
End If

End Function


'the final look would be something like this

Sub TitleChange()
'define array
myarray = Range("A1:A100")
' Define the pattern
Dim pattern As String: pattern = "<h*>*</h*>" 'looks for the header tags
Dim f As Variant

    For Each f In myarray
        If f Like pattern = True Then Capital (f) 'changes all string to lower case except countries (to retain proper case) and acronyms (to retain uppercase)
    Next f

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of the function you found online?

Comment: @jBuchholz, have included the code.  Thanks

Comment: You can change to lowercase like that `If StrComp(v(j), UCase(v(j)), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then v(j) = StrConv(v(j), vbLowerCase)` but this lower Argentina too ..

Comment: Thanks @YasserKhalil this would output:  <h1>hr policies and procedures for hiring - argentina ltd</h1> all lowercase though, as well as the LTD and HR word.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the countries in an array

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Capital("HR Policies and Procedures for Hiring - argentina LTD")
End Sub

Function Capital(ByVal s As String)
    Dim a, v As Variant, j As Long
    a = Array("Argentina", "Egypt", "Enland")
    v = Split(s, " ")
    For j = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        If StrComp(v(j), UCase(v(j)), vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then v(j) = StrConv(v(j), vbLowerCase)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(v(j), a, 0)) Then v(j) = StrConv(v(j), vbProperCase)
    Next j
    Capital = Join(v, " ")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @YasserKhalil, this will address the country names, how about the other abbreviation or acronym that we are not sure will be used?  <h1>hr policies and procedures for hiring - Argentina ltd</h1>

Comment: Hi, @YasserKhalil, added additional code in the question, can we get the output of the FindAcronyms userdefined function and lowercase the rest of the string?  Thanks

Comment: Not so clear. Can you post the desired output? Do you need to get the acronyms?

Comment: Basically I have an HTML page source code that I clean from downloads and format.  One of the line items I would search is the header items, those texts in between <h1></h1> to <h5></h5>.   The title texts characters here should be in lowercase, except acronyms (which were uppercase) and country names (propercase).  The desired output for the example is:   <h1>HR policies and procedures for hiring - Argentina LTD</h1>. Thanks @YasserKhalil

Comment: Just to give further information, I would download 10 - 30 HTML pages with 100 to 150 lines of HTML code with 5 to 20 header tags.  The title tag formats should be all lowercase except acronyms / abbreviations in uppercase, country names in proper case.  Usually the acronyms and countries are in their correct case, i.e. upper and proper respectively.  The rest are usually proper case that needed to be in lowercase.

Comment: This is already done in the UDF in my answer .. All will be lowercase except acronyms and the list of countries that would be put in the array inside the UDF.

Comment: I tested with the UDF to this string:  <h1>HR HR Policies and Procedures LTD for Hiring - england LTD</h1> this was the output:  <h1>hr Hr policies and procedures Ltd for hiring - England ltd</h1>  the HR is Hr and LTD is Ltd in between.  On the ones near the tag its at lower cases, HR at hr and LTD at ltd.  Can we take the output from the UDF FindAcronym and put it in the array? And refer to country list to proper case?  Thanks @YasserKhalil

Comment: Added the `Sub TitleChange()` how the code would seem to look like @YasserKhalil

Answer (score 0):

Added UDF that parses HTML code, used the Sub Test above as UDF Capital and UDF to bring together. Welcome suggestions to make it cleaner or more efficient

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A5")
' Define the pattern
Dim pattern As String: pattern = "*<h?>*</h?>*"
' Check each item against the pattern
    For Each cell In rng
        If (cell Like pattern = True) Then
            cell.Offset(0, 16).Value = cell.Value
            cell.Offset(0, 16).Value = joinCell(Capital(StripHTML(cell)), cell.Offset(0, 0).Value) 'used UDF for striping innertext, applying rules and joining back string
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```